# Git remote repo merge with local; Change location

Tags: git, merge, location, local

I want to use a github repo (qml.net) in my project. I tried qtcreators interface but this never worked, as it still couldn't find qml.net.
I thought maybe qtcreator doesn't support working directly with cloud repos (Visual Studio could do this).

What I want to do now is to store the /.git directory (inside my project) and a git cloned version of qml.net somewhere else maybe on a different drive entirely.

Which commands do I need for this, and how do I make sure that qtcreator knows the new location?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is to have one directory on my working machine with the remote named 'origin' set to my usual working cloud repo (e.g. github). I'd then create a second remote origin named 'qml'.

I could then do normal operations between my working machine and github. To update 'qml' I could just execute:

```
git push qml master
```

which would push the current master branch from my machine to qml. Normally my local master would be up-to-date with 'origin/master' when I do this.

If you have newer commits on 'qml', then you can execute:

```
git fetch qml
git reset --hard qml/master
```

The above assumes that you're already on your local master branch and that it doesn't have any commits on it than 'qml/master'

Comment: This works for me, thank you very much! Now I have full controll of how I handle the files.